# How to properly convert a date into a ISO-8601 Week number format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datepart

ISO-8601 states that week numbers are to be formated as `YYYY-W##` - observe that the week number should be two digits as 01, 02, ...

```
SELECT cast(DATEPART(YYYY, CreationDate) as varchar) + '-W' + 
       cast(DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GETDATE())`
```

The problem is that this gives the week number as 1, 2, ...

What is the correct way of extracting 2020-W01, ...

Answer (score 4):

The original question text relates to a simple formatting issue of the ISO_WEEK number, but I feel there is a bigger issue here with the concatenation of the year part. Simply concatenating DatePart YYYY and ISO_WEEK will yield incorrect (or at least unexpected) results for days in week 1 and/or 53. Notably dates like 2014-12-31 are part of week 1, but not 2014-W01. It is part of 2015-W01. Similarly, 2016-01-01 will be part of 2015-W53, not 2016-W53. In order to determine the Iso Year-Week the year must be corrected to take this into account:

```
With
    Dates (Date) As (
            Select Convert( date, N'2014-12-31' )
Union All   Select Convert( date, N'2015-01-01' )
Union All   Select Convert( date, N'2015-12-31' )
Union All   Select Convert( date, N'2016-01-01' )
    )
Select
    src.Date
,   Concat( Case
        When DatePart( Month, src.Date ) = 12 And DatePart( ISO_WEEK, src.Date ) = 1 Then DatePart( Year, src.Date ) + 1
        When DatePart( Month, src.Date ) = 1 And DatePart( ISO_WEEK, src.Date ) > 50 Then DatePart( Year, src.Date ) - 1
        Else DatePart( Year, src.Date )
    End, N'-W', Right( Concat( N'00', DatePart( ISO_WEEK, src.Date ) ), 2 ) ) As IsoYearWeek
From
    Dates src
;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT cast(DATEPART(YYYY, CreationDate) as varchar) + '-W' + Right('0'+cast(DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,CreationDate) as Varchar),2)
```

Comment: This does not yield the correct result for 2021-01-01. It returns 2021-W53, where it should return 2020-W53. See http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/413279/datepart-iso-year-for-iso-week

Comment: Broken link @Mike

Comment: The `ISO WEEK YEAR` is not always the `CURRENT YEAR` (ie: `01/01/2017` is in the iso week `2016W52`), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date