# Easiest Way to Group By Date

Tags: sql

Microsoft SQL:

I have a database query that converts a string to a date and then aggregates:

```
WEEK(CAST(myDateField as DATE)) AS dt
...
GROUP BY dt
```

However, this `WEEK` function returns a number.  If I have multiple years, I need to add a `YEAR()` function.  Is there any better way to `CAST/CONVERT` this to one single date field?  It would be fine (even preferable) if the dates were aggregated by week with a date format, too:

2010-01-07
2010-01-14
2010-01-21 etc

Comment: Which version of SQL (Microsoft, mySQL, Oracle, etc)

Comment: I'm trying to convert a query that used `INTNX` in SAS if that gives you any frame of reference for what I was doing.

Comment: See this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322453/how-to-properly-convert-a-date-into-a-iso-8601-week-number-format-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want as output.  It seems like you are trying to get the first date of each week.

If your data is "dense" (meaning you have data on every date), you can do:

```
select min(myDateField) as dt
...
GROUP BY year(myDateField), week(myDateField);
```

Despite the `cast()` in your code, I am believe that a field called "MyDateField" is stored as a date/datetime and not as a string.

If you want to convert your date to ISO standard:

```
select convert(varchar(10), min(myDateField), 121),  -- puts it in YYYY-MM-DD format (my favorite)
```

And, finally, maybe you don't want to use `week()` at all.  Maybe you just want to find the first day of the week.  You can do this by subtracting the day of week from the date:

```
select dateadd(dd, datepart(dw, 1 - myDateField), myDateField) as dt
...
GROUP BY dateadd(dd, datepart(dw, 1 - myDateField), myDateField);
```

With this structure, the `group by` and `select` have the same argument.

Comment: This was perfect, I'm actually passing through a query to Teradata and it's SQL is a little bit different.  This gave me the idea I needed to get the job done, thanks.

Comment: Thanx for not accepting same answer posted 20 minutes earlier.

Comment: It's not the same answer.  Gordon posted DATEADD stuff that gave me the idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL there is function: `STR_TO_DATE()`

You have to specify date format, for example:

`STR_TO_DATE('2013-05-01','%Y-%m-%d');`

For MSSQL you need to define what exact format the date is by format id:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '10/23/2016', 101) -- mm/dd/yyyy

SELECT convert(datetime, '2016.10.23', 102) -- yyyy.mm.dd

SELECT convert(datetime, '23/10/2016', 103) -- dd/mm/yyyy

SELECT convert(datetime, '23.10.2016', 104) -- dd.mm.yyyy

SELECT convert(datetime, '23-10-2016', 105) -- dd-mm-yyyy
```